# Add additional data to the model data returned by a Django serializer

Tags: django, serialization

I am using the Django REST framework to create an API. I would like to add data from more than one model to the serialised output.

At the moment my serialiser looks like this:

```js
class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('url', 'owner', 'item_type')
```

I would like to add an

```js
item_cost
```

value from my Costs model to the serialised output (a different cost for each item in the Item model). I would also like to add a unix timestamp value to the serialised output (one value to be placed at the end of all of the other serialised output).

My serialiser is used in a view as follows:

```js
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all().order_by('-date_added')
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```

I can't work out how to add the other data items to the serialised output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `SerializerMethodField` from `rest_framework.serializers` and create a method that returns the value you are looking for, eg:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    cost = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_cost(self, obj):
        value = ... # calculate your value
        return value

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('url', 'owner', 'item_type', 'cost')
```

Reference in the docs: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: That is perfect Gustavo! Is there a way to access the query params from the calling url in the get_cost function so I can do an action that depends on the query?

Comment: Yes you can. From inside the method, you can access the `QueryDict`: `self.context.get('request').query_params`